# Data Visualisation for Dataframe having 3 columns

Tags: python, plotting, matplotlib

I have the below data, I am looking for a effective visualization or graphical method (in Python) to understand how the err is distributed with respect to min and max.

```
Data_X_err.head()
Out[137]: 
     min    max   err
0  35435  35933  1.40
1  35155  36382  3.43
2  35305  36042  2.07
3  35216  36225  2.82
4  35196  36259  2.98
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plt(Data_X_err.min, Data_X_err.err)
ax2.plt(Data_X_err.max, Data_X_err.err)
```

Alternatively you could use seaborn's pairplot

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set(style="ticks")

sns.pairplot(df)
```

[image]